# Firebase- how to restrict access permission in child nodes?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

How could I set rules to restrict someone access child node form machine?
for example :
     00041802000001,00041802000002,00041802000003,...etc

My rules are:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "machine":{
      "$machine":{
        ".read": "data.child('giftIn').val() >10" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it don't work, permission problem happened:

> Listener at /machine failed: permission_denied

what rules could make someone access 00041802000002 only?

[image: firebase realtime database]

Comment: The documentation has pretty good examples of securing access to a specific node: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data Did you try anything yet? Sharing what you tried will not only show that you've taken the effort, but (more importantly) it will help us understand what you're trying to do and where you are struggling.

Comment: @Frank,i modify my rules as below:{
  "rules": {
    "machine":{
       "$machine":{
           ".read": "data.child('giftIn').val() >10"
        }
    }
  }
}
but it don't work, permission problem happened

Comment: ＠Frank, detail as "Listener at /machine failed: permission_denied"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're granting access to *each* specific individual machine. This means that you can access each machine once you know its key (e.g `00041802000002`).

But you're then trying to read *all* machines: `/machine`. Since you don't have read permission there, the read is rejected.

You will either need to grant access to read *all* machines, or read a specific machine.

If you were expecting that reading `/machine` would filter the child nodes to only return the ones with a `giftIn` value of greater than 10, you're unfortunately in for a disappointment. Firebase security rules cannot be used to filter out data. The reason for this is that the rules are enforced when you attach a listener, not for every individual child node.

If this fact that rules cannot filter data is new to you, I recommend you study the [documentation section on it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters) as well as some of the many [previous questions on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfirebase-security%5d%20rules%20are%20not%20filters).

Comment: 感謝您的回答。我之前已經閱讀過文檔，並且我明白實時數據庫規則不能作為過濾器。現在我確認你的答案和firebase的文件說...非常感謝....Next i would modify my front-end application and database structure to make it possbile

Comment: Perfect HunterChen! If you run into problems, just post another question with the JSON, rules and code.